# Database connection lifetime - Short lived vs per request

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-pooling, structuremap

I have an MVC application, using StructureMap for IoC.

Within the application, data access is 95% via Entity Framework; however there are a few raw ADO.NET repositories that make use of an `IDbConnection` instance.

At present I register `IDbConnection` with the IoC container like this...

```
init.For<IDbConnection>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use(() => this._connectionFactory.CreateConnection(config.ConnectionString));

init.Forward<IDbConnection, DbConnection>();
```

... and inject `IDbConnection` into the raw ADO.NET repositories where necessary.

However, at present I have `_connectionFactory.CreateConnection()` returning an **OPEN** connection with the intention of allowing StructureMap to close the connection at the end of the request.

Is it wise to do this?

Is it better to share a single open connection throughout the lifetime of the request, or open/close only where necessary and keep the connections short lived?

Comment: Do you want the EF processes and the ADO.NET processes to run in one transaction?

Comment: At present this isn't a requirement. However would going down a certain route make this difficult in future?

Comment: Maybe, if you want to wrap your code in a `TransactionScope` (which is a recommended way to bundle db interactions in one transaction) all connections must be opened when this scope is active. Also, but this may be off the point, they should have *exactly* the same connection string to prevent MSDTC to kick in.

Comment: I don't think the connection strings will be a problem. I'm more interested in whether it's bad practice to leave a connection open for the entire scope of the request.